# Перевести сообщение на странице Ошибки 404

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нет-в-transifex

От редактора: строка [Transifex:3985](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40265830?key=e910471f8e1f2e273ade9a0597634e89), переведена, но не используется.

> We're sorry, we couldn't find the page you requested.

---

Ситуация подобна обсуждаемой [в этом](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251647/portuguese-stack-overflow-404-page-has-mixed-english-and-portuguese) вопросе, только воспроизводится на Stack Overflow на русском.

Я зашел на [страницу-заглушку для 404-ой ошибки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/getmetothe404page) и увидел это:

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

Там говорится, цитирую:

> We're sorry, we couldn't find the page you requested.

Эта строчка должна быть переведена на русский язык.

Я не говорю по русски, поэтому не знаю, как ее корректно перевести.

Comment: Maybe that is some standerd over all sites modeled after SO

Comment: Translate: "Нам очень жаль, но мы не смогли найти запрошенную страницу".

Comment: Thank you for your report. I've proposed several translations. Once one of them gains enough votes, it will be added via Transifex. This question will receive a [meta-tag:status-completed] mark.

Comment: (Не знаю, как правильно «апнуть», пишу здесь). Проблема актуальна и спустя год с момента оригинального сообщения. Как на [Stack Overflow на русском](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/sdfkjsg;ldfsgjkdf), так и на [Meta Stack Overflow на русском](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/sdflsjafdljsdf).

Answer (score 10):

К сожалению, запрошенная страница не найдена.

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, требуемой страницы нет на сайте.

Answer (score 2):

Нам очень жаль, но мы не смогли найти запрошенную страницу.